# Assert does not throw expected error

Tags: contract-development

I am trying to implement a TicTacToe smart contract:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.19;

contract TicTacToe {
    uint8 public boardSize = 3;
    address[3][3] board;

    address public player1;
    address public player2;

    constructor() public {
        player1 = msg.sender;
    }

    function joinGame() public payable {
        assert(player2 == address(0)); 
        player2 = msg.sender;
    }
}
```

However, in the `joinGame` function the `assert(player2 == address(0));`  does not throw an error when I try to join a game using a different address from the one that initially joined the game. It basically replaces the `player2` var with the new address that joined instead of throwing an error (since there should be only 2 players in the game)

Please help thanks!

Comment: I put this on remix and it works as expected, It doesn't allow me to join the game when player 2 is different from zero, which is what the code is supposed to do. On another topic, you may want to use require instead.

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you want to do is replace:

```
assert(player2 == address(0));
```

with:

```
require(player1 != msg.sender && player2 == address(0));
```

This check makes sure that `player1` cannot be `player2` and `player2` is available.